# MVC 5 / .Net Framwork with Unity IoC - Registering an ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, unity-container

For my current project, a WebAPI / MVC environment, I am using Unity IoC for DI.

As MVC 5 / .Net framework do not have an inbuilt logging so I need something, but want to also use DI for the referencing the service, but I don't know how to set up / register the logger service.

For all other services in the application, its simply a case of adding the mappings to the `RegisterTypes` in `UnityConfig.cs`

Target deployment will be Azure Web App service, so I need something with those capabilities.

If I was able to use .Net Core, problem solved, its all there ready, but unable to do that (don't ask why, but I am trying) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to select the logging library - common ones are log4net and [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#installing-nlog).
There are already tons of materials with installation instruction, including official notes. You don't need DI for NLog it already has a static helper, but you can encapsulate it into your own abstraction. 
 So you need to have an interface, for example, `ILogger` and it's realization - class `NLogLogger`. Put the methods you need inside `ILogger` in manner you like - it can be `LogError(msg, ex)`, `LogDebug(msg)`, `LogInfo(msg)`, or instead one method with level param `Log(level, msg, ex)`, where level your is enum: `Error`, `Debug`, `Trace` etc. You can put that interface inside application core.

The `NLogLogger` would be the concrete implementation of the logger, so you can later substitute it. Put it into infrastructure. 
Implement it along with official tutorial you can find on GitHub repo.

You can configure NLog with XML file, just put it in app root, and copy one of example for writing logs into file or console.

At the end just bind interface with class inside DI configuration, like any other abstraction. Now you can inject it in every place you want.